# nested sql query on same table in codeignater

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my project, I am saving category and subcategory records in same table `tbl_categories` as if parent_cat_id is '0' then its main category otherwise parent_cat_id will contain the cat_id of main category.

I want to list the subcategory with the fields:

- 1)caterory id(of subcategory)
- 2) category name
- 3) sub category name.

I am unable to implement the query for above

```
SELECT cat_name 
FROM `tbl_categories` 
WHERE cat_id IN (
  SELECT parent_cat_id FROM `tbl_categories`
) <-this is what i implemented in phpmyadmin
```

i want to implement it in codeignater

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $sql = "select t1.name as category_name, t2.name as parent_cat_name

         from tbl_categories as t1

         left outer join 
         tbl_categories as t2 

         on t2.id = t1.parent_cat_id";

  $query = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
  return $query;
```

Comment: thanks..but its returning all the values and I want only those records which have subcategories

Comment: Ok... As far I understand - You want only sub_categories which is having parent_id. If so... then you can use: `select t1.cat_name as category_name, t2.cat_name as parent_cat_name from (Select * FROM tb_category_list WHERE parent_cat_id > 0) as t1 left outer join tb_category_list as t2 on t2.id = t1.parent_cat_id`

Answer (score 0):

With reference to @M NIPUN SARKER answer, the query can also be written as -

```
$this->db->select('t1.name as category_name, t2.name as parent_cat_name'); // select what you might want to select 
$this->db->from('tbl_categories t1');
$this->db->join('tbl_categories t2', 't2.id = t1.parent_cat_id', 'left'); 
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
return $query;
```

It will generate the category in `category_name` and its parent in `parent_cat_name` which you can access by

```
// suppose $your_variable contains the result generated through query
foreach($your_variable as $variable){
    echo 'Category Name: '.$variable->category_name.' Parent Category Name: '.$variable->category_name.'<br>';
}
```

See if this helps you.